# Как выстроить данные в одну строку

Tags: html

Прошу помощи, нужно вывести данные из следующего кода в одну, горизонтальную строку:

```
<span class="col_01">
    <?php if (($params->get('show_cat_pic')) && ($cat_all[$i]->image != "")) { ?>
                <img src="./images/stories/<?php echo $cat_all[$i]->image; ?>"
                   alt="picture for subcategory" height="265" width="220" />&nbsp;
    <?php } else {
        ?>
                <a <?php echo "href=" . sefRelToAbs($link); ?> class="category<?php
                 echo $params->get('pageclass_sfx'); ?>" style="text-decoration: none"><img
                  src="./components/com_realestatemanager/images/folder.png"
                   alt="picture for subcategory" height="265" width="220" /></a>&nbsp;
    <?php } ?>
</span>
```

Как сейчас:

[image: Как сейчас]

Пример кода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вероятно `div {display: inline-block}`

Comment: Спасибо, я пробовал данный вариант, но его перебивает то, что на втором скрине "user agent stlesheet" (

Comment: на крайний случай всегда можно попробовать вот так `div {display: inline-block !mportant;}`

Comment: а вообще, судя по классам, у вас там какая-то сетка, возможно фреймворк, используется. надо узнать принцип работы и от этого уже плясать